# returning to the specific html table line

Tags: php, html

Suppose there is a large html table containing values from mysql database.
Each td is a link to the form for editing specific value
The question is how to return after editing via "back" button to the html table starting from the already edited line

Here is the table structure:

```
$query="SELECT id, number, name FROM vlan1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed");
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print "<td>$line[0]</td>";
    print "<td>$line[1]</td>";
    print "<td>$line[2]</td>";
    print "<td><a name=\"del\" href=edit_vlan/update.php?del=".$line[0]."\">Изменить</a></td>\n";
    print "<td><a name=\"del\" href=showVlan2.php?del=".$line[0].">Удалить</a></td>";
?>

<?php
print "</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

How to navigate to a certain line of the table, after editing it in the other form?

Comment: The browsers back button retrieves the file from cache an wont show the  updated fields.

Comment: On click of `edit` of `td` save the corresponding `tr` number to cookie. then while on click of `back` get the `tr` number from the cookie and use js code to scroll table to the location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can do this, depending on how your 'back' functionality is implemented, but every way will incorporate the use of `id` attributes as anchors, to jump to specific points.

Given the following row:

```
<tr id="my_key_1">
```

If you redirect a user to:

```
mypage.example.com/myTable#my_key_1
```

The browser will scroll down to make sure that row is visible and at the top of the viewport if possible.

Comment: and how to navigate via php variable?

Comment: That's worked, at last. The trick was just to properly catch a php variable. Thanks a lot)